# How to select attribute that is method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Maybe a question is little confusing but I will explain.

I wrote a query to select some data and I need to select title but title isn't column in table it is method in model (combined from two fields). How I can in query use that title method? I tried some things but it keeps telling me that title field is missing.

```
Concert.select('entity_changes.updated_at, concerts.id, concerts.title').joins('left join entity_changes on entity_changes.id = concerts.id')
       .where(:clazz_name => 'Concert').order('entity_changes.updated_at DESC').limit(5)
```

and I get this error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "title" does not exist
```

Comment: What query are you trying to run?

Comment: This would appear something suited for full-text search. What db are you using? If Postgresql, it comes with built in full-text capability. Let me know and I will show you how to use it.